# How to Use Expanded in flutter

Tags: flutter, terminal

I have a problem with my code, and I don't know what's going on because nothing lights up.
When I reload my code, and click something on the screen my terminal shows this :

```
> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical
viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  ListView
  file:///Users/dominikkolber/Desktop/algotrading/worked_project/lib/widgets/transactions_list.dart:15:25

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1365:15)
#1      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1426:6)
#2      RenderBox.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2342:12)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1763:9)
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#8      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#10     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#14     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#16     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:279:14)
#17     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#18     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:54:11)
#19     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:897:45)
#20     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:932:32)
#21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#22     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:54:11)
#23     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:830:43)
#24     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:932:32)
#25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#26     _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:558:14)
#27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#38     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#40     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#41     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:925:7)
#42     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:243:7)
#43     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:407:14)
#44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#47     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#48     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1371:11)
#49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#56     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:54:11)
#57     RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:570:43)
#58     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:597:12)
#59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#60     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#62     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#65     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#66     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#67     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#68     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#69     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#70     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#71     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3362:13)
#72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#73     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#75     _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:743:15)
#76     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#77     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#78     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#79     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#80     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#81     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#82     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#83     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#84     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:546:11)
#85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#86     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#87     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#88     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:118:14)
#89     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1784:7)
#90     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:153:14)
#91     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1641:7)
#92     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:884:18)
#93     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:453:19)
#94     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:874:13)
#95     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#96     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#97     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#98     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:865:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)

The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#cbc71 NEEDS-LAYOUT
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
  needs compositing
  creator: Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#28017] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
    RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#e8dad] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope
    ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#d4bfb] ← Scrollable ← ListView ← ConstrainedBox ← ⋯
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=300.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  axisDirection: down
  crossAxisDirection: right
  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#a246f(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null,
    ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> BouncingScrollPhysics ->
    RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#b67a4, ScrollDirection.idle)
  anchor: 0.0
This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
    center child: RenderSliverPadding#ab96d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
      child: RenderSliverList#474d3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#cbc71 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#cbc71 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#14767 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#8657d relayoutBoundary=up15
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#b5a18 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#fffbd relayoutBoundary=up13
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#12b1c relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#59657 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#69ea6 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#0e0b0 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#a112f relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#45682 relayoutBoundary=up7
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#8bbd3 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#617d0 relayoutBoundary=up5
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#dffcd relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#66524 relayoutBoundary=up3
NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#5238d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#01cd6 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSingleChildViewport#45682 relayoutBoundary=up7
NEEDS-PAINT

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value

Another exception was thrown: Bad state: Future already completed
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize': RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#14f8e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1940:12)
#3      RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:179:9)
#4      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2785:25)
#5      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:787:31)
#6      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2780:33)
#7      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:417:12)
#8      Rend<…>
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize': RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#14f8e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1940:12)
#3      RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:179:9)
#4      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2785:25)
#5      BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:787:31)
#6      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2780:33)
#7      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:417:12)
#8      Rend<…>
```

I really don't know what's the problem i was watching one of tutorial, below is my code if someone want to help

https://gist.github.com/agentkolby/313a65939eb4a8e0a136f5fa7bc36925

Comment: Show the part of the code that is giving you the error, will helps. I think you are using a the expanded inside a row and theres no another widget inside.

Comment: problem is i dont really know where is the error

Comment: It should be in this file (lib/widgets/transactions_list.dart:15:25) transactions_list.dart line 15.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below. Change the code in user_transactions.dart

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
          TransactionList(_userTransactions),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can cannot use `Expanded` in `Column`.